# Generic method which return Interface

Tags: c#

I would like to write a generic method that return DAL interfaces but it doesn't works.

It's possible to make this :

```
public MyInterface GetDAL()
{
   return new DAL(); // DAL implements MyInterface
}
```

But not this :

```
public TInt GetDAL<TInt, TDAL>()
{
   return new TDAL();
}
```

or this

```
public TInt GetDAL<TInt, TDAL>()
{
   return (TInt)new TDAL();
}
```

I know I could return concrete class instead of interface but I don't understand why it doens't works, if TDAL implements TInt.

I have 10 DAL classes and I don't want to write 10 methods.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

It does work if you tell the compiler the [*constraints*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for `TDAL`:

```
public TInt GetDAL<TInt, TDAL>() where TDAL : TInt, new()
{
   return new TDAL();
}
```

This tells the compiler that `TDAL` must implement `TInt` and have a parameterless constructor.
So now the compiler knows that for any type argument for `TDAL` the expression `new TDAL()` will work and that the result is assignable to `TInt`.

Comment: Thank you, it works but this methods is used as OperationContract with WCF so it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

`new TDAL()` won't work because not all classes have a parameterless constructor, or inherit from `TInt`.

You need to add type constraints to your method e.g.

```
public TInt GetDAL<TInt, TDAL>() where TDAL : new(), TInt
{
   return new TDAL();
}
```

Then when you use your method, the compiler will enforce a compatible type to be used.

```
MyInterface dal = GetDAL<MyInterface, DAL>(); // Will compile

MyInterface dal = GetDAL<TMyInterface, string>(); // Won't compile
```